# Does Microsoft PowerBI Supports Azure AD authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

The requirement is to create a managed identity where Azure Purview will scan the metadata of PowerBI.I think, using the managed identity to grant access to the target resource (here PowerBI) However, that target resource must Support Azure AD authentication. Hence wanted to know if  Microsoft PowerBI supports Azure AD authentication.

If yes, how to create a managed identity where Azure Purview will scan the metadata of PowerBI? If no, what is the other way to achieve the above-said requirement?

Note, I was referring [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-power-bi-tenant?tabs=Scenario1) but was unable to figure out the right way forward.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not doing something programmatically. I need to know how can I achieve the given requirement using managed identity and what role I must give to that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Power BI uses Azure AD to authenticate users who sign in to the Power BI service.

The managed identity is created when your Microsoft Purview resource is created. In order for Purview to be able to scan Power BI, you need to set up authentication by creating a security group, adding the Purview Managed identity to the security group, and enabling the Allow service principals to use the **read-only Power BI admin APIs** feature switch. That permission gets inherited from the security group to the managed identity.

To run a new scan you need to have the Power BI Administrator role and need a Power BI license.

The article you linked has all of the guidelines to achieve what you described. You need to [enable metadata scanning in for the organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-metadata-scanning-setup#enable-tenant-settings-for-metadata-scanning) and follow the prerequisites.

Then you need to register the Power BI tenant in Microsoft Purview, and create a security group in your Azure AD tenant. If you are using Managed Identity as authentication method, add your Microsoft Purview managed identity to the security group by selecting "Add members". Then you can [associate the security group with the Power BI tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-power-bi-tenant?tabs=Scenario1#associate-the-security-group-with-power-bi-tenant).

See also:

[Purview and Power BI](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/security-compliance-and-identity/microsoft-power-bi-and-microsoft-purview-work-better-together/ba-p/2912388)